# Listing's meaning as in motion or movement?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

It's the scene where he's being pushed back

> He stumbled back, **listing**, unsteady on his feet.

What does listing in this sentence mean?

Source: Novel, Pines, Blake Crouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's leaning, maybe about to fall.

[American Heritage Dictionary "list"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=list)
3. list (verb)
To lean or cause to lean to the side:
*The damaged ship listed badly to starboard.*